# How to create an alias for a record in this case?

Tags: alias, record, elm

I have a question about records: Lets say I have a function that takes a record, like this:

```
getId : { file | id : String } -> String
getId file = file.id
```

I could pass in something like this: `{ id = "abcd", name = "hi.txt"}` because it's got an `id`. All good so far. My question is: could I create an alias for the "file" in the function type signature? What would the syntax for that be?

Answer (score 8):

You could define an alias for this extensible record called `WithID` like this:

```
type alias WithID a = { a | id : String }
```

Now you can update the signature of `getId` like so:

```
getId : WithID a -> String
getId file = file.id
```